# Alternate version of grammar not working as I'd prefer

Tags: grammar, raku

This code parses `$string` as I'd like:

```
#! /usr/bin/env raku

my $string = q:to/END/;
aaa bbb   # this has trailing spaces which I want to keep

       kjkjsdf
kjkdsf
END

grammar Markdown {
    token TOP {  ^ ([ <blank> | <text> ])+ $ }
    token blank { [ \h* <.newline> ]  }
    token text { <indent> <content> }
    token indent { \h* }
    token newline { \n }
    token content { \N*? <trailing>* <.newline> } 
    token trailing { \h+ }
}

my $match = Markdown.parse($string);
$match.say;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
｢aaa bbb

       kjkjsdf
kjkdsf
｣
 0 => ｢aaa bbb
｣
  text => ｢aaa bbb
｣
   indent => ｢｣
   content => ｢aaa bbb
｣
    trailing => ｢   ｣
 0 => ｢
｣
  blank => ｢
｣
 0 => ｢       kjkjsdf
｣
  text => ｢       kjkjsdf
｣
   indent => ｢       ｣
   content => ｢kjkjsdf
｣
 0 => ｢kjkdsf
｣
  text => ｢kjkdsf
｣
   indent => ｢｣
   content => ｢kjkdsf
｣
```

Now, the only problem I'm having is that I'd like the `<trailing>` level to be in the same level of the hierarchy as `<indent>` and `<content`> captures.

So I tried this grammar:

```
grammar Markdown {
    token TOP {  ^ ([ <blank> | <text> ])+ $ }
    token blank { [ \h* <.newline> ]  }
    token text { <indent> <content> <trailing>* <.newline> }
    token indent { \h* }
    token newline { \n }
    token content { \N*?  } 
    token trailing { \h+ }
}
```

However, it breaks the parsing. So I tried this:

```
    token TOP {  ^ ([ <blank> | <text> ])+ $ }
    token blank { [ \h* <.newline> ]  }
    token text { <indent> <content>*? <trailing>* <.newline> }
    token indent { \h* }
    token newline { \n }
    token content { \N  } 
    token trailing { \h+ }
```

And got:

```
 0 => ｢aaa bbb
｣
  text => ｢aaa bbb
｣
   indent => ｢｣
   content => ｢a｣
   content => ｢a｣
   content => ｢a｣
   content => ｢ ｣
   content => ｢b｣
   content => ｢b｣
   content => ｢b｣
   trailing => ｢   ｣
 0 => ｢
｣
  blank => ｢
｣
 0 => ｢       kjkjsdf
｣
  text => ｢       kjkjsdf
｣
   indent => ｢       ｣
   content => ｢k｣
   content => ｢j｣
   content => ｢k｣
   content => ｢j｣
   content => ｢s｣
   content => ｢d｣
   content => ｢f｣
 0 => ｢kjkdsf
｣
  text => ｢kjkdsf
｣
   indent => ｢｣
   content => ｢k｣
   content => ｢j｣
   content => ｢k｣
   content => ｢d｣
   content => ｢s｣
   content => ｢f｣
```

This is pretty close to what I want but it has the undesirable effect of breaking `<content>` up into individual letters, which is not ideal. I could fix this pretty easily after the fact by massaging the `$match` object but would like to try to improve my skills with grammars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

quick and dirty

```raku
my $string = q:to/END/;
aaa bbb  

       kjkjsdf
kjkdsf
END

grammar Markdown {
    token TOP {  ^ ([ <blank> | <text> ])+ $ }
    token blank { [ \h* <.newline> ]  }
    token text { <indent>? $<content>=\N*? <trailing>? <.newline> }
    token indent { \h+ }
    token newline { \n }
    token trailing { \h+ }
}

my $match = Markdown.parse($string);
$match.say;
```

lookahead assertions

```raku
my $string = q:to/END/;
aaa bbb  

       kjkjsdf
kjkdsf
END

grammar Markdown {
    token TOP {  ^ ([ <blank> | <text> ])+ $ }
    token blank { [ \h* <.newline> ]  }
    token text { <indent>? <content> <trailing>? <.newline> }
    token indent { \h+ }
    token newline { \n }
    token content { [<!before <trailing>> \N]+  }
    token trailing { \h+ $$ }
}

my $match = Markdown.parse($string);
$match.say;
```

a little refactoring

```raku
my $string = q:to/END/;
aaa bbb  

       kjkjsdf
kjkdsf
END

grammar Markdown {
    token TOP { ( <blank> | <text> )+ %% \n }
    token blank { ^^ \h* $$  }
    token text { <indent>? <content> <trailing>? }
    token indent { ^^ \h+ }
    token content { [<!before <trailing>> \N]+  }
    token trailing { \h+ $$ }
}

my $match = Markdown.parse($string);
$match.say;
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to accomplish what I want with a negative lookahead assertion:

```
    token TOP {  ^ ([ <blank> | <text> ])+ $ }
    token blank { [ \h* <.newline> ]  }
    token text { <indent>? <content> <trailing>? <.newline> }
    token indent { \h+ }
    token newline { \n }
    token content {  <.non_trailing>  } 
    token non_trailing { ( . <!before \w \h* \n>)+ \S* }

    token trailing { \h+ }
```

The `<.non_trailing>` suppresses the individual characters from appearing in the match object and the `. <!before \w \h* \n>)+ \S*` bit will match any character not followed by white space and a new line and the `\S*` bit gets the character left over from the negative lookahead.

**OUTPUT**

```
｢aaa bbb

       kjkjsdf
kjkdsf
｣
 0 => ｢aaa bbb
｣
  text => ｢aaa bbb
｣
   content => ｢aaa bbb｣
   trailing => ｢   ｣
 0 => ｢
｣
  blank => ｢
｣
 0 => ｢       kjkjsdf
｣
  text => ｢       kjkjsdf
｣
   indent => ｢       ｣
   content => ｢kjkjsdf｣
 0 => ｢kjkdsf
｣
  text => ｢kjkdsf
｣
   content => ｢kjkdsf｣
```